# Angular - ng-repeat - get all json subdata in 1 list

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, arrays

I have a json describing rooms with a sub-array 'actions', describing what actions have to be done to the room.

> Room > Actions: {1, 2, 3}

I'd like to show all actions from all rooms on one page & able to filter/sort them.

At the moment I have come to this.

```
<div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="action in room.actions">
```

This shows all the actions, but grouped by room.

Action 1 - room 1

Action 2 - room 1

Action 3 - room 2

Action 4 - room 2

...

I would like the actions to be 'independent' from their room, so I can sort and filter them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want the __actions__ to be independent, create a new set for them.

Comment: yes, I'd like them to be independent, but when I create a new array and fill it with them (in the same controller), nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for the help! With a little help from Kyle and inspiration from Mohammed, I managed to solve my problem.

```
$http.get('rooms.json').success(function (data) {
        campus.rooms = data;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < data[i].actions.length; j++) {
                campus.allActions.push(data[i].actions[j]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/l7rCkclpT1S9f8buk6n9?p=preview)

Using nested repeaters, you can use filters to scope the actions to a specific room.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.rooms = [
        {id:1, text:'room 1'},
        {id:2, text:'room 2'},
        {id:3, text:'room 3'}];
    $scope.actions = [
        {room:{id:1, text:'room 1'}, name:'action 1', number:1 },
        {room:{id:2, text:'room 2'}, name:'action 2', number:2 }, 
        {room:{id:3, text:'room 3'}, name:'action 3', number:3 }];
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
          {{ room.text }} <br />
          <div ng-repeat="action in actions | filter:{ room:room } | orderBy: 'number' ">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ action.name }}
          </div>
     </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your rooms and actions depending on the Json data you have in the response, by using 'for' loop and '$stateParams', and you need an Id for each room so you can filter actions by roomId.
**NOTE: I'm using AngularJs here.**

example: (response from server):

**JSON:**

```
{"rooms ":[
    {"roomId":"1", "value":"Room 1", "action":"Action 1"}, 
    {"roomId":"2", "value":"Room 2", "action":"Action 2"},
    {"roomId":"3", "value":"Room 3", "action":"Action 3"}
]}
```

**JS:**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "your server url here: from where you get the json data"
}).
success(function(res) {
    $scope.Rooms= res;
    for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].roomId== $stateParams.roomId) { 
            $scope.actions = res[i];
            break;
            console.log(res);
        }
    }
}).
error(function(err) {
console.log(err);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list">
{{actions.action}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a beginner with AngularJS, could you explain the use of $stateParams?